# Как получить вчерашнюю дату на JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, дата

Как получить правильною (формат даты дд.мм.гггг и при условии если сегодня 01.10.2019 получить 30.09.2019) вчерашнюю дату на JavaScript?

Comment: Уточните в вопросе (кнопка "править"), что такое "правильная" вчерашняя дата?

Comment: Если задаться целью обойтись без дополнительных переменных для хранения промежуточного результата, то можно так: `console.log(new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() - 1)))` :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Подключи moment.js, я его использую и восторгаюсь.
На нем это будет выглядеть как **moment().subtract(1, 'days').format('DD.MM.YYYY');**

Answer (score 5):

Как вариант:

```
new Date(Date.now()-86400000)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function dtime_nums(e) {
  var n = new Date;
  n.setDate(n.getDate() + e);
  return n.toLocaleDateString();
}

console.log(dtime_nums(-1));
```